# arc-jsapi How can I st_geometry using a lookup field?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, arcgis-js-api

I am using the st_geometry field and try to view the PNU code value.

I tried two ways.

1. oracle DB query.

   select a.pnu from LP_PA_CBND_4600000000 a
   where sde.st_contains(a.shape,
   sde.st_point(177566.6728471977,160430.12935426735, 4))=1

When an event occurs, click the map object
i got the  evt.mapPoint(x,y).
4 is my srid. 
this way is took a long time. and query was down...

2. i used the arcgis api`s IdentifyParameters

my code is follows.

```
  PoiClick : function(map, evt) {
             G_evt =evt;
             console.log("ClickPoint ==== "+evt.mapPoint);
            var targetLayerId = 'LP_PA_CBND'; 
            var url = map.Layers.getLayerInfo(targetLayerId).SVC_URL;
            var map = map.getMap();
            //파라미터 설정.
            var idParams = new krcgis.core.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
            G_idparams =idParams;
            idParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
            idParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
            idParams.returnGeometry = true;
            idParams.tolerance = 3;
            idParams.layerOption = krcgis.core.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
            idParams.width = map.width;
            idParams.height = map.height;

            krcgis.Function.GetPoiInfo(url, idParams);
            return evt.mapPoint;
        },

        //POI 정보를 가져온다.
         GetPoiInfo : function(url, idParams) {
              idTask = new krcgis.core.tasks.IdentyfyTask(url);

            idTask
            .execute(idParams)
            .addCallback(function (response) {
                G_response = response;
                if (response) {
                    return response;
                }

            })
            .addErrback(function (error) {
                console.log('GetPoiInfo result error=', error);
            });
        }
```

It could be obtained in this way code pnu.

However, this way is different from the value that gets pnu code depending on the zoom level.

I want to get a single pnu code in a single x, y values.

how to get pnu code?

Database table  :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IdentifyTask can be a little tricky, because it takes into account zoom levels, therefor it doesn't always return the same results.

I suggest that you use [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html). Just one problem - it doesn't have tolerance parameter, but you can buffer your evt.mapPoint and get Polygon.